# marmalade sdk UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: ios, sdk, blackberry-playbook, marmalade

I am new to marmalade sdk and i got an error starting IwGxHelloWorld.mkb on win 7.
Can anyone help with it pls? Thanks!
Error itself:

```
D:\Marmalade\6.1\s3e\makefile_builder\mkb.py      
D:\Marmalade\Project\HelloWorld\IwGxHelloWorld.mkb
Building project: d:/Marmalade/Project/HelloWorld/IwGxHelloWorld.mkb
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Marmalade\6.1\s3e\bin\\..\..\s3e\makefile_builder\mkb.py", line 209, in
run()
File "D:\Marmalade\6.1\s3e\bin\\..\..\s3e\makefile_builder\mkb.py", line 137, in run
main(sys.argv)
File "D:\Marmalade\6.1\s3e\bin\\..\..\s3e\makefile_builder\mkb.py", line 32, in main
exit_code = mkb_main.run(argv)
File "d:\sdkbuild\sdk\main\s3e\makefile_builder\mkb_main.py", line 3461, in run
File "d:\sdkbuild\sdk\main\s3e\makefile_builder\mkb_main.py", line 3619, in run2
File "d:\sdkbuild\sdk\main\s3e\makefile_builder\mkb_main.py", line 2913, in process_mkb_for_platfo
rm
File "d:\sdkbuild\sdk\main\s3e\makefile_builder\plugins\s3e_vc6.py", line 142, in output
File "d:\sdkbuild\sdk\main\s3e\makefile_builder\plugins\visualstudioemitter.py", line 309, in outp
ut_proj_fles
File "d:\sdkbuild\sdk\main\s3e\makefile_builder\plugins\emitter.py", line 740, in convert
File "d:\sdkbuild\sdk\main\s3e\makefile_builder\templates\win32_vcproj.py", line 1426, in run
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 795: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is language of your Windows? Russian? Looks like you pressed Russian В somewhere.

Comment: yeah, the problem was user name in Russian.